The Python terminal in vscode remote cannot automatically activate the selected conda environment
Have checked:

The automatic activation of the base environment is not enabled in the bashrc.
The conda environment is available and can be activated from the vscode remote terminal using the "conda activate envName" command.
In summary, the vscode remote terminal appears to have only started bash and cannot automatically activate the conda environment.

vscode remote automatically activates the currently selected conda environment.

I don't understand your question. In item 2 you write: conda ... can be activated from the terminal, and in the next sentence terminal ... cannot automatically activate conda. So your main problem is to make conda automatically activated, so that you don't have to do it by hand? If so, should it this happen in every terminal, or only in a vscode terminal?

I want vscode Remote Terminal to automatically activate the selected conda environment when opened.like pycharm，When the terminal is opened, the selected environment can be automatically activated,You do not need to manually run the conda activate command.The environment name appears before the terminal prompt

What speaks against doing this in the startup file for your shell?
